# Buzzy sounds when mouse moving

Tags: mouse, windows-11

As title says I have buzzy sounds when mouse is moving. I've seen a lot of questions on web about it. Common answer is either change mouse usb port or just forget about it because it's not that dangerous (grounding issues). Switching port didn't help.

But I found something that casts suspicion that this is a software problem. This sound ONLY appear when mouse pointer is hovering some window or around it (on the same monitor).
What I mean it doesn't produce any sound while moving on a desktop.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it happen in a minimal boot configuration? Does it happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all mouse cursor effects (eg, shadow, trails, color, etc.)?  Also, try changing your mouse cursor theme to see if helps.  Any advanced UI effect (eg, transparency, animation, smoothing, etc.) may attempt to use hardware acceleration -- esp. if your GPU and memory are not shielded and located near your sound processor or speakers.  Personally, I might suspect a hook or driver.  Sometimes a Process Monitor (ProcMon) capture might help isolate the culprit.  In ProcMon, you'll need to review the loaded modules list and stack traces when the issue occurs.

Comment: Do you get the same noise when you connect the same mouse to a different computer, or a different mouse to the same computer? Is the sound coming from the mouse, the computer, or the speakers?

Comment: Considering it only appears on certain graphical elements, I would suspect the video card rather than the mouse tbh. Could be **coil whine**. If it doesn't disappear with a different mouse that's probably it.

Comment: @leeharvey1 i tried enable\disable mouse after-cursor effect - it didnt help. Ill try with ProcMon and respond.

Comment: @music2myear thanks for a tip, no sound using another (wireless) mouse. So can I draw a conclusion that issue is only mouse-related?

Comment: Can you localise the source of the sound?